# Is this ground plane correct?

Tags: grounding, differential

I am trying to improve my grounding skills

This is a RJ45 connector on one side, a signal transformer, and a pin header on the other side (this is a prototype, and i am splitting the design in parts for simplicity)

The idea is to connect this to a switch ic later.

So, I have a earth ground on the border, and a ground solid place with only 1 point to gnd under the diff pairs.

What do you think?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I am seeing many differential pairs...

Comment: where's the circuit diagram for this? The purpose of a single connection to ground is supposed to be what?

Comment: there are two diff pairs Rx and TX going from the RJ45 connector, to the transformer, and then to the other connector

Answer (score 1):

1. In this case, extending the ground plane so far to the right is a bad idea.  The transformer give you isolation.  Extending the same ground plane under both sides defeats that in part.

   What's with the large red area on the right?

   If the blue is ground tied to the left side of the isolation, then why not let it use up as much as possible of one layer on that side of the isolation gap?

Comment: thanks for the comment. The red plane is earth. C4 is a capacitor that connects earth from the rj45 shield to gnd

Comment: 3. so, you mean, extend the ground plane to the border to all the corner, right?

Comment: @Jav: C4 then also defeats isolation to some extent.  Yes, why not extend the blue ground as far as you can, on its side of the isolation barrier.

Comment: and what about pins? the holes wont make paths and loops?